# is there is a way to extract lines in between 3 files that are in common based on one column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, bioinformatics

I have 3 files, space separated which have about 3.4 million lines (but they don't have exactly the same number of lines and they are sorted by the "Marker" column). They look like this:

- `head neu1`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker      MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.229925  T  G         + 0.650403 1594
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.287014  T  C         + 0.955449 1594
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.097867  T  C         - 0.290455 1594
     1 100002882 1:100002882:T:G 0.287014  G  T         + 0.955449 1594
     1 100002991 1:100002991:G:A 0.097867  A  G         - 0.290455 1594
     1 100004726 1:100004725:G:A 0.132058  A  G         + 0.115005 1594
  ```
- `head  nep1`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction    pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2300430  T  G         - 0.1420030 1641
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2867150  T  C         - 0.2045580 1641
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0975015  T  C         - 0.0555507 1641
     1 100002882 1:100002882:T:G 0.2867150  G  T         - 0.2045580 1641
     1 100002991 1:100002994:G:A 0.0975015  A  G         - 0.0555507 1641
     1 100004726 1:100004726:G:A 0.1325410  A  G         - 0.8725660 1641
  ```
- `head ret1`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2322760  T  G         - 0.230383 1608
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2882460  T  C         - 0.120356 1608
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0982587  T  C         - 0.272936 1608
     1 100002882 1:100002883:T:G 0.2882460  G  T         - 0.120356 1608
     1 100002991 1:100002991:G:A 0.0982587  A  G         - 0.272936 1608
     1 100004726 1:100004726:G:A 0.1340170  A  G         - 0.594538 1608
  ```

Is there is a way to create another 3 files, say `neu2`, `nep2`, `ret2` which would only contain lines where the value in the "Marker" column (the 3rd column) is the same for all 3 of the original files?

I should mention that the output files should contain all 9 column from the initial files.

The expected output would be these 3 files:

- `head neu2`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker      MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.229925  T  G         + 0.650403 1594
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.287014  T  C         + 0.955449 1594
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.097867  T  C         - 0.290455 1594
  ```
- `head  nep1`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction    pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2300430  T  G         - 0.1420030 1641
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2867150  T  C         - 0.2045580 1641
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0975015  T  C         - 0.0555507 1641
  ```
- `head ret1`

  ```
     Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N
     1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2322760  T  G         - 0.230383 1608
     1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2882460  T  C         - 0.120356 1608
     1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0982587  T  C         - 0.272936 1608
  ```

Headers of each of 3 files are present in the initial files and in the resulting files and are these 9:

```
Chr  BP  Marker MAF  A1  A2    Direction   pValue    N
```

Comment: What is the matching criteria in the Marker column? There is nothing in common in those fields. Add the expected output to your question?

Comment: Hi the values in Marker column are like this: 1:100000012:G:T, and it can be found in all 3 files for example

Comment: By what is in the files, that looks like the `BP` column. Do you, in fact, want the column that is in that format? What is the matching criteria? Is it `1:100000012:G:T`? Is there also supposed to be a tab or several spaces at the beginning of each line in those files?

Comment: I want to preserve all 9 columns from the original files but only keep the rows  that are matching by Marker column

Comment: If you can preprocess the files to strip the header line or lines (it is not clear from your post if the headers are in fact present in the files), you can use the `join` command.

Comment: Then again I ask, what string do you want to match by in the third column? Do you want to edit the files in place, send to standard output, or send the output to other files? Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: the whole string, for example these: 1:100000012:G:T, 1:100000827:C:T...

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for that useful input I updated the post with the expected output

Comment: @q.undertow Headers are present in every file and I just updated the post with that info

Answer (score 1):

This should be both fast and memory efficient. It uses `join` (part of [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/))
 and `field` (part of [tangetools](https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/field)):

```
# This finds the matching lines and makes it into a big file with 25 columns
join -1 3 -2 3 neu1 nep1 | join -1 1 -2 3 - ret1 |
  # Now split the right columns
  # field is https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/field
  tee > >(field 2-3,1,4-9 > neu2) >(field 10-11,1,12-17 > nep2) >(field 18-19,1,20-25 > ret2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ../tst.awk
ARGIND < 4 {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) {
        ARGV[ARGC] = FILENAME
        ARGC++
    }
    if ( !seen[ARGIND,$3]++ ) {
        cnt[$3]++
    }
    next
}
FNR == 1 {
    close(out)
    out = FILENAME
    sub(/1/,"2",out)
}
cnt[$3] == 3 {
    print $0 " > " out
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f ../tst.awk neu1 nep1 ret1
Chr        BP          Marker      MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N > neu2
1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.229925  T  G         + 0.650403 1594 > neu2
1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.287014  T  C         + 0.955449 1594 > neu2
1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.097867  T  C         - 0.290455 1594 > neu2
Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction    pValue    N > nep2
1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2300430  T  G         - 0.1420030 1641 > nep2
1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2867150  T  C         - 0.2045580 1641 > nep2
1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0975015  T  C         - 0.0555507 1641 > nep2
Chr        BP          Marker       MAF A1 A2 Direction   pValue    N > ret2
1 100000012 1:100000012:G:T 0.2322760  T  G         - 0.230383 1608 > ret2
1 100000827 1:100000827:C:T 0.2882460  T  C         - 0.120356 1608 > ret2
1 100002713 1:100002713:C:T 0.0982587  T  C         - 0.272936 1608 > ret2
```

Change `print $0 " > " out` to `print > out` when you're done testing to actually generate the output files you want. The above uses GNU awk for `ARGIND`, if you don't have GNU awk then just add `FNR==1 { ARGIND++ }` as the first line of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a nice problem. If you are sure that the files are sorted ascending by the third column, I propose to use similar method to the merge-join from the “SQL world”. Sorting of the files must be done using the same sorting function, which is used to compare strings in bash. The script below requires bash. It should be called in following way:

```
$ script file1 file2 file3
```

It will create 3 output files: file1.out file2.out file3.out. They contain lines from the respective source files, which have value in the third column, which is present in all input files. All lines having such value are in the ‘.out’ files.

```
#!/bin/bash
Fil1="$1"
Fil2="$2"
Fil3="$3"
# Opening file descriptors  for reading
exec 10<"$Fil1"
exec 20<"$Fil2"
exec 30<"$Fil3"
# Open output files
exec 11>"$Fil1".out
exec 21>"$Fil2".out
exec 31>"$Fil3".out
# First line is copied without changes.
IFS= read -r -u 10 Line1
printf "%s\n" "$Line1" >&11 
IFS= read -r -u 20 Line2
printf "%s\n" "$Line2" >&21 
IFS= read -r -u 30 Line3
printf "%s\n" "$Line3" >&31 
# Prepare to walk through files, searching for identical values in the third column.
IFS= read -r -u 10 Line1
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC1=0; else RC1=1; fi
read -r F11 F12 F13 F1 <<<  "$Line1" 

IFS= read -r -u 20 Line2
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC2=0; else RC2=1; fi
read -r F21 F22 F23 F2 <<<  "$Line2" 

IFS= read -r -u 30 Line3
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC3=0; else RC3=1; fi
read -r F31 F32 F33 F3 <<<  "$Line3" 

while [ $RC1 -eq 0 ] && [ $RC2 -eq 0 ] && [ $RC3 -eq 0 ]
do
  while [ "$F23" \< "$F13" ]
  do
    IFS= read -r -u 20 Line2
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC2=0; else RC2=1; break; fi
    read -r F21 F22 F23 F2 <<<  "$Line2" 
  done
  if [ $RC2 -ne 0 ]; then break; fi
  if [ "$F23" = "$F13" ]
  then
    FFF="$F23"  
    while [ "$F33" \< "$FFF" ]
    do
      IFS= read -r -u 30 Line3
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC3=0; else RC3=1; break; fi
      read -r F31 F32 F33 F3 <<<  "$Line3" 
    done
    if [ $RC3 -ne 0 ]; then break; fi
    if [ "$F33" = "$FFF" ]
    then
      while [ "$F23" = "$FFF" ]
      do
        printf "%s\n" "$Line2" >&21 
        IFS= read -r -u 20 Line2
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC2=0; else RC2=1; break; fi
        read -r F21 F22 F23 F2 <<<  "$Line2" 
      done
      while [ "$F13" = "$FFF" ]
      do
        printf "%s\n" "$Line1" >&11 
        IFS= read -r -u 10 Line1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC1=0; else RC1=1; break; fi
        read -r F11 F12 F13 F1 <<<  "$Line1" 
      done
      while [ "$F33" = "$FFF" ]
      do
        printf "%s\n" "$Line3" >&31 
        IFS= read -r -u 30 Line3
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC3=0; else RC3=1; break; fi
        read -r F31 F32 F33 F3 <<<  "$Line3" 
      done
      if [ $RC1 -ne 0 ] || [ $RC2 -ne 0 ] || [ $RC3 -ne 0 ]; then break; fi
    fi
  fi  
  while [ "$F33" \> "$F23" ]
  do
    IFS= read -r -u 20 Line2
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC2=0; else RC2=1; break; fi
    read -r F21 F22 F23 F2 <<<  "$Line2" 
  done
  while [ "$F23" \> "$F13" ]
  do
    IFS= read -r -u 10 Line1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then RC1=0; else RC1=1; break; fi
    read -r F11 F12 F13 F1 <<<  "$Line1" 
  done
done
# close files 
exec 10>&-
exec 11>&-
exec 20>&-
exec 21>&-
```

The script reads the files only once, advancing alternately. Thus, all input files must be opened simultaneously. This is possible in bash, but shell is not a good tool for such processing.
At large input files, you may get significantly better results by writing this in C. It will be also easier to give better structure to the code, and fully control the process.